# Passing no argument to a method that expects an argument

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to pass no arguments to a method that expects an argument. I have this so far but I can't seem to get it working:

```
// HTML 

// this one doesn't pass an argument
<el-button @click:search>Button 1</el-button>

// this one does pass an argument
<el-button @click:search('hey')>Button 2</el-button>

// JS
method: {
    search (searchBy) {
         // if there's a value
         if( searchBy ) {
              console.log(searchBy);
         // if there's no value output this intead
         else
              console.log("nothing to search by");
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried just using `@click:search()` ?

Comment: The reason it doesn't work (aside from the syntax errors in the question) is because click handlers without an argument specified will receive the `event` object by default.

Comment: ohhh there's the explanation I'm looking for. Thanks @Bert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try search() instead of search

```
<el-button @click:search()>Button 1</el-button>
```

even you have not closed the `if` bracket

Comment: I would've though that just passing the method name would suffice and automatically thing that there's no argument being passed

Comment: @AlfieMcNarutoad using the method name will return the function definition and to call it you have to use brackets ()